# Analysis of a sentence from 風立ちぬ

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, expressions

> 私はとうとう焦れったい**とでも云う**ような目つきで、お前の方を見返した。

I know there is という, but this is my first time to see でも after と, so I can't understand the uncommon grammar structure of とでも云う. I am wondering whether でも here has the same usage as that of `コーヒーでも飲みませんか` &`避暑にでもいったら元気になるかもしれない`

Answer (score 4):

> 「私{わたし}はとうとう焦{じ}れったいとでも云{い}うような目{め}つきで、お前{まえ}の方{ほう}を見返{みかえ}した。」

≒

> 「私はとうとう『焦れったい！』とでも云うような目つきで、お前の方を見返した。」

「～～とでも云{い}う」 means "as if to say ~~".

I suggest that you remember this as a common set phrase.  The 「と」, of course, is the quotative particle.

> I am wondering whether でも here has the same usage as that of コーヒーでも飲みませんか &避暑にでもいったら元気になるかもしれない

Yes, it does at least ***roughly***.

> "**Finally, with a look as if to say 'I'm irritated', I stared back at you**."

Comment: Can I omit でも in this sentence?